# Mapview inside a ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mapview

I am following this tutorial [here](http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/07/android-custom-expandable-listview-with-imageview-and-textview.html) and I am trying to change the ImageView for a MapView but I don't know how to do it, because there it explains passing an array of strings for populating the ImageView.

I tried to do something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use MapView?

Comment: I did use mapview on older projects, but on a simple activity using a onMapReady class, Im not complete newbie, but I stock on this issue

Comment: If you only want to show a marker on map and have no other interaction, I suggest to use google static map which renders map as a static image and you can show that image inside an ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know how to use Google MapView follow [this tutorial](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-mapview-example-tutorial/).

If you want to know how to pass the data to your child adapter, instead of array of strings construct an array of latitude-longitude pairs as follows:

```
List<LatLng> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
locationList.add(new LatLng(55.854049, 13.661331));
locationList.add(new LatLng(56.854049, 14.661331));
.
.
.
```

In your `Child.java` class remove `int Image` and instead add:

```
private LatLng location;

public int getLatLng() {
    return location;
}

public void setLatLng(LatLng location) {
    this.location = location;
}
```

And in you `SetStandardGroups()` method do the needful changes. instead of `ch.setImage(Images[j])` add following:

```
ch.setLatLng(locationList.get(j));
```

After that if you know how to work with list adapters you should be able to  populate the data in you `ExpandListAdapter` class.